# Using an object in code, which is instantiated in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, object

I am trying to experiment making simple GUI application.

In it I have made a simple class called `consle`. I am using a button click to trigger an event Button_Click_1. This should in turn call the function `wrStr` which changes the value of variable `change` internally. This changed value should reflect in the GUI because the variable `change` is also bound in the XAML code.

The problem is, I do not know how to access the `consle` type object instantiated in XAML code. If I get the name of the object instantiated in XAML I could just say `<NameOfObject>.wrStr()` inside the `Button_Click_1` function.

The XAML code is given below:

```
<Window x:Class="TryBinding.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TryBinding" 
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">                    

    <Grid>

    <Button Content="Set44" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="244,37,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="Button_Click_1"/>

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="339,76,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Source=consle, Path=change, Mode=OneWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

</Grid>
```

The cs code is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace TryBinding
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();           
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}

public class consle
{
    public string mainstr {get; set;}
    public int change { get; set; }

    public consle()
    { 
    }

    public void wrStr()
    {
        change = 44;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can't simply use a class name (like your "consle") as the `Source` object of a binding. You may instead set the MainWindow's `DataContext` property to an instance of `consle`, like `DataContext = new consle();` and remove the `Source` from the Binding. I'd strongly suggest to read the [Data Binding Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx) article on MSDN.

Comment: Later, you will always be able get the `consle` instance back from the `DataContext`, like `var c = (consle)DataContext;`.

Comment: It may also be very helpful to get a book about WPF and take the time to read the basic chapters, including those about data binding.

Comment: Ok. Actually I read the msdn articles but I couldn't understand many sections from them. But I think reading the basic chapters from some book will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Adam Nathan's "WPF Unleashed" explaines pretty much everything.

Comment: Thanks that's what I started reading right now.